# FileHelpers - 'FieldConverter' is not valid on this declaration type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, filehelpers

I'm trying to set the date format of a CSV file I'm reading from via the FieldConverter attribute but I'm receiving the following error -

> Attribute 'FieldConverter' is not valid on this declaration type. It
>   is only valid on 'field' declarations.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class SomeViewModel
{   
    public int account { get; set; }

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime doc_dte { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in the error message you can't use attribute `FieldConverter` on property, only on field. So, just change your property to a field:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
public DateTime doc_dte;
```

Comment: /facepalm. Thanks!

Comment: @user1645888 Glad to have been of help